# Pass explicit NULL value to stored procedure from T-SQL not from application

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

At wits end with this
How do I pass a null value to my stored procedure within SSMS?
I have set two of my parameters to optional eg.

```
 --This is inside my storedproc
 @name varchar(50)
 @surname varchar(50) = null,
 @text varchar(255) = null,
```

Now to execute

```
 --Now execute without the 'text'
 EXEC sp_bla 'Noob Question Name', 'Noob Surname'
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the call, it should work as-is. Are you getting an error?

Comment: You have answered your own question. "I have set two of my parameters to optional" - by giving them default values that's exactly what you have done. It should execute as you have shown. You can also pass null in  - sp_bla 'The Name', null, 'The text'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
EXEC sp_bla NULL, 'Noob Question Name', 'Noob Surname'
```

Basically, just pass NULL as parameter value in the required position

Answer (score 3):

Try this
If u want to define all the three parameters then

```
EXEC sp_bla @name = 'Noob Question',@surname = 'Noob',@text = 'Newtext'
```

If u want to define any two

```
EXEC sp_bla @name = 'Noob Question',@surname = 'Noob'
```

or

```
EXEC sp_bla @name = 'Noob Question',@text = 'Text'
```

If u do not have any of the other two

```
EXEC sp_bla @name = 'Noob'
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply leave the Stored Proc as it is, then execute without the parameters that are not required.

Example: `EXEC sp_bla @name = 'Noob Question Name', @surname = 'Noob Surname'`

Just leave any parameter that accepts null to set it as null when executing the SP